# Global window object in lightning helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller, helper

After getting an answer to [Preserve a JavaScript variable between component calls of the client-side code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227584/preserve-a-javascript-variable-between-component-calls-of-the-client-side-code) question (which says there is a separate wrapper object around the browser's `window` object for each component) I got curious about the `window` object inside helper.

As I know while there is a separate controller created for each lightning component instance, there is only one helper for each type of lightning component instances.

So, may I always expect that the `window` object accessed inside a helper will refer to the `window` object of a controller which called the helper?

Comment: window object be once per component .If you want to share a common window object you can use static resource with a JavaScript file

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, I do not want to share it. My question is to which component will the `window` object in helper be related?